# not able to install netCDF4 in python without HDF5

Tags: python, importerror, hdf5, netcdf

i have been trying to install the python package for netcdf4 using the package provided in 
   ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/

i have installed the netcdf-4.3.3.1.zip
extracted it and followed the instructions given in 
  https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-install/Quick-Instructions.html

2.1 Building NetCDF Without HDF5

If you don't want netCDF-4/HDF5, then build like this:

```
 ./configure --prefix=/home/ed/local --disable-netcdf-4
 make check install
```

(Replace “/home/ed/local” with the name of the directory where netCDF is to be installed.)

i replaced '/home/ed/local' with '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'

after this i ran the command ' nc-config --version'

```
netCDF 4.3.3.1
```

but i am not able to import the module in python i am geting that

```
ImportError: No module named netCDF4
```

nor i am able to find any folder related to netcdf4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

i just need to read the .nc file data if their is any other way help me

thank you

EDIT -------
 i realised that you require hdf5 so i got the package

then when i follow the instructions given in the link 
 when i run  the instructions for hdf5 folder i got some errors related  to conversion of dos files to unix i fixed them by saving them with ending in unix/linux . but i did not do all the files as after the first two files there where no errors 
   then i use the commands 
     make 
     sudo make install
 i get multiple output as

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/akhil/hdf5-1.8.16/src'
   Makefile:972: .deps/H5.Plo: No such file or directory
   Makefile:973: .deps/H5A.Plo: No such file or directory
   Makefile:974: .deps/H5AC.Plo: No such file or directory
   Makefile:975: .deps/H5Abtree2.Plo: No such file or directory
   Makefile:976: .deps/H5Adense.Plo: No such file or directory

and many errors of the same format

so i ignore them since there was no specific error

igo do the commands for netdf4 file

once i do the first command 
    LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include ./configure --    enable-netcdf-4 --enable-dap --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local

i get an error

```
  configure: error: Can't find or link to the hdf5 library. Use --disable-netcdf-4, or see config.log for errors.
```

then i go into the netcdf4 python 
   i run sudo python setup.py install

error

netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:237:22: fatal error: H5public.h: No such file or directory
 #include "H5public.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

help

Comment: You have installed the netCDF C library (which you should not install at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), you need to install a python library as well, e,g. http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/ . You should ofcourse first check if both these are already available as a package for your OS/distro.

Comment: First, are You sure You want python-netcdf4 without HDF5? You will not be able to open most netcdf files this way, because NetCDF4 file format actually needs HDF5 and only old, NetCDF3 files can be used without.
Second problem is described by @nos, but I would also suggest using packages provided by OS